# How to retain Angular model and watch when using JQuery UI plugin Selectize

Tags: jquery-ui, angularjs

Plunker:  http://plnkr.co/edit/ElXFi2mo44VpLVsaooOJ

I am modifying a working web app to utilize a jQuery UI plugin called Selectize. Previously I had an input element bound to the controller and a watch placed on that variable.  I added the required code to selectize the component which has undone my watch and binding because this plugin modifies the DOM elements and obscures my bound element with new elements.

I would prefer to stay with the angular watch rather than calling a method in selectize to watch the value.

Comment out lines 7-16 to see that the watch is called correctly on every input change.

```
<input id="itemQuery" type="text" placeholder="Search" class="form-control" ng-model="myValue">
```

And the script:

```
angular.module('Sample.controllers', [])
    .controller('mainController', ['$scope', 
        function($scope) {
            $scope.myValue="";
            $('#itemQuery').selectize({
                delimiter: ',',
                persist: false,
                create: function(input) {
                    return {
                        value: input,
                        text: input
                    }
                }
            });

            $scope.$watch('myValue', function(newValue, oldValue) {
               alert("Old value: " + oldValue + " New value: " + newValue);
            });
}]);
angular.module('Sample', ['Sample.controllers']);
```

Comment: Here is an example that works with arrays and allows you to specify a list of objects to autocomplete on.
http://plnkr.co/edit/7zfHOr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing you can do is avoid implicit DOM manipulation inside controller and write a directive for that instead.

<kbd>[Updated Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/haSBrKoQniZg4OBfob9B?p=preview)</kbd>

```
App.directive('sampleSelectivize', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.selectize({
          delimiter: ',',
          persist: false,
          create: function(input) {
            return {
              value: input,
              text: input
            }
          }
      }).on('change', function(event) {
        console.log($(this).val());
      });
    }
  };
})
```

And apply it to your input

```
<input sample-selectivize id="itemQuery" />
```

If you've checked the documentation, there are different events can be helpful for you
https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/events.md

Comment: I am a much closer to understanding this.  I am also aware that I need to sit down and uncover the mystery that is directives.  I have a final piece that I still do not understand.  After I add a watch to the bound variable in the scope, it is still not updating.  I have updated your plunker here. http://plnkr.co/edit/ieqQRWBub8ZJ8zOdEhEs?p=preview

Comment: You watch will not work because selectize does not use your input box. You can check for `onType` callback and see the updated demo above.

Comment: That is exactly how I did it in my actual project.  I am calling scope.$apply in onType but passing in the element value + the str that onType passes.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to codef0rmer for pointing me in the right direction.  The solution was to tell angular that the scope needed updating and to provide it with the new value for this components.  The key part being that I needed to include `require: '?ngModel'` in my directive initializers and then angular provided it as the 4th parameter to the link function.

```
angular.module('Sample.controllers', [])
        .controller('mainController', ['$scope',
          function($scope) {
            $scope.myValue = "";
            $scope.$watch('myValue', function(newValue, oldValue) {
              console.log("OldValue: " + oldValue + " New value: " + newValue);
            });
          }]).directive('sampleSelectivize', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      element.selectize({
        delimiter: ',',
        persist: false,
        create: function(input) {
          return {
            value: input,
            text: input
          }
        }
      }).on('change', function(event) {
        scope.$apply(applyChange);
      });
      function applyChange() {
        ngModel.$setViewValue(element.context.value);
      }
    }
  };
});
angular.module('Sample', ['Sample.controllers']);
```

I found this resource to be helpful though incomplete: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController

Solution plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/ieqQRWBub8ZJ8zOdEhEs?p=preview
Note: It uses console.log rather than alert.